# ASP.NET WEBAPI add custom route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have the new .NET WebAPI up and running and I am trying to add a new route to my project so that I can see the `SettingsController` in action.  I have added my route to the `Global.asax` file within the RegisterRoutes method but I receive a 404 error when I try and browse to: `sampleUrl:12345/settings/index`.  I am able to see: `sampleUrl:12345/home/index` without issue.

Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Settings",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Do I need to have an `ActionResult Index()` in my `SettingsController`?

Answer (score 2):

Your settings route is redundant. What you are probably missing is the index method in settings controller.

Comment: OK, so remove that route for Settings from Global.asax.  I do have a folder named Settings in my Views folder and that folder has an Index.cshtml file in it.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: I have a ProductsController that is executed by default.  This works without issue.  There is not a Index method in the ProductsController.  There is one in the HomeController however.  I am using the WebAPI starter project.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio installed on this laptop, but if you have 5 minutes, scan thru [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)